# ERROR in getting file from Amazon S3 using python(3.8)

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, pickle, python-3.8

I am trying to get data from Amazon S3 and store it into a variable (file such as .pkl file).

And I am getting the following error:

**ERROR:**

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

**CODE for S3**

```
class S3Mgr:
    def __init__(self,bucketName):
        self.aws_access_key_id= CONFIG.S3[0]
        self.aws_secret_access_key = CONFIG.S3[1]
        self.region_name = CONFIG.S3[2]
        self.bucketName = bucketName

    def __connect(self):
        self.s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key,
            region_name=self.region_name
            )
    def retrieveModel(self,fileName):
        self.__connect()
        a = self.s3.download_fileobj(Bucket=self.bucketName, Key="fcm/project/"+str(fileName))
        return a['Body'].read()
```

**CODE for pickle**

```
import pickle
from io import BytesIO

S3obj = S3mgr("mybucket")
model = S3obj.retrieveModel("model.pkl")

data = BytesIO(model)
model = pickle.load(data)

prediction = model.predict(inputArray)
```

Above inputArray is the array of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, replace `download_fileobj` with `get_object` in your s3Mgr class's `retrieveModel` method.

Something like this:

```
def retrieveModel(self,fileName):
        self.__connect()
        a = self.s3.get_object(Bucket=self.bucketName, Key="fcm/project/"+str(fileName))
        return a['Body'].read()
```

I Hope, it works. Ping if any progress or need any help.

Cheers  !